# Consistent Android Studio error "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'" for using an Android library's resources

Tags: android-studio

I know there are lots of posts for the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'" that can be resolved with some remedies and I have read many. I feel that I need to post a separate question for my case that is different from others that I have read.

library net.my.foo is shared by many apps. The following pattern is consistent among all apps if an app uses a resource ID of the library (e.g., net.my.foo.R.string.test).

1. Android Studio shows the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'" for the use of "net.my.foo.R.string.test".
2. This has no effect on building and running the app. The app runs flawlessly.
3. This occurs no matter how many times Android Studio is restarted and how many times the Android Studio cache is invalidated.

Could anyone shed some light on this and offer a tip on its remedy? This is not a showstopper but a constant nuisance.

Comment: Also you can try : import net.my.foo.R.string.test.R;

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I had the same issue.

1. Go to 'Build' then click on 'Clean Project'
2. Click on 'Sync Project'

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. This does not work. As I mentioned in my post, I even took the nuclear option of invalidating caches many times to no avail.